# Know current user id anywhere from my application

Tags: entity-framework, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

I am working on a blazor project.

Users are authenticated with asp.net-core identity component.

I want to know the id of current user. But i want to know it anywhere in my code, not only in razor pages (for example in an EF entity class).

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you think about creating a service which all other service could invoke it to get user id from the service? Or, do I misunderstand?

Comment: I can create a service but how can i know current user in this service ? Thanks

Comment: For example, after signing in, you can store the user information in the frontend in localstorage/sessionstorage, or you can send the user information to the server and save it in session, or no need to save, just get the user information from httpcontext.

Comment: I mean that user information can be found in http request context, you can get current user in your backend code.